# for php to Postgres FOR LOOP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a for php and I want to include it in a postgre function,but I can not translate it to postgre. The idea is to have the date range between date 1 and date 2 in an array where the index is that same date.
Thanks in advance.

My code in php:

```
$meses_intermedios = array();

for ($e = '2016-03-01'; $e <= '2017-07-01'; $e = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($e . "+ 1 month"))) {
    //From the date '2016-03-01' to the date '2017-07-01', I accumulate the intermediate dates
         $meses_intermedios[$e] = $e;
    }
```

the expected result should be

```
$meses_intermedios['2016-03-01'] => 2016-03-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-04-01'] => 2016-04-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-05-01'] => 2016-05-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-06-01'] => 2016-06-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-07-01'] => 2016-07-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-08-01'] => 2016-08-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-09-01'] => 2016-09-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-10-01'] => 2016-10-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-11-01'] => 2016-11-01
$meses_intermedios['2016-12-01'] => 2016-12-01
$meses_intermedios['2017-01-01'] => 2017-01-01
$meses_intermedios['2017-02-01'] => 2017-02-01
$meses_intermedios['2017-03-01'] => 2017-03-01
$meses_intermedios['2017-04-01'] => 2017-04-01
$meses_intermedios['2017-05-01'] => 2017-05-01
$meses_intermedios['2017-06-01'] => 2017-06-01
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to do in Postgres, but you might find [the `generate_series` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) helpful.

Comment: Hi IMSoP, The idea is to have the date range between date 1 and date 2 in an array where the index is that same date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in case it serves someone.. the solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing.bucle_date_array(
    start_date date,
    end_date date)
RETURNS date[]
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 0
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
date_exe date := start_date;
array_date date[];
BEGIN

WHILE date_exe <= end_date
LOOP
    -- MAKE YOUR STUFF
    RAISE NOTICE '%', date_exe;
    array_date := array_append(array_date,date_exe);
    date_exe := date_exe + interval '1 month';
END LOOP;

RETURN array_date;

END;

$BODY$;
```