# iteration foreach in array Postgres with array of dates

Tags: arrays, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I have a problem for the iteration of an array of dates:
The values of the array they come loaded with another function.

```
DECLARE
  i INT;
  array DATE[]; -- values array : '{2017-01-01,2017-02-01,2017-03-01,2017-04-01}'
BEGIN
  FOREACH i IN ARRAY array
      LOOP       
        INSERT INTO table (id, date)
        VALUES (i);
  END LOOP;

Error: the input syntax is not valid for integer: «2016-02-01»
```

I tried to change the declaration from `i` to date, without success, and I also tried to assign `i` (date) the first value of the array (`i = array[1];`) without success.

Does anyone know how to fix it or what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use strings: `array[date '2017-01-01', date '2017-02-01', ...]`

Comment: I do not understand a_horse_whit_no_mane, the array loaded with another function is DATE, how change values to no string?. Thank you

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that you are populating that array using `'{2017-01-01,2017-02-01,2017-03-01,2017-04-01}'` - but `2017-01-01` will be treated as a number (2017 minus 1 minus 1), not as a date. If you want real dates in there populate it with proper date literals.

Comment: The problem is in the function what gives me back the array?
here are this funccion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656259/for-php-to-postgres-for-loop
Thak you very much a_horse_whith_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i searched and found a solution: I put it in case someone is interested:

```
for i in  coalesce(array_lower(array, 1),1)..coalesce(array_upper(array, 1),1) 
    loop
       INSERT INTO table (id, date)
       VALUES (i);
    end loop;
```